# Accuracy/ Positional error in converting GIS data from one format to another

Tags: shapefile, convert, error, dwg

Is there a chance of error creeping in to the positional accuracy of features/objects when converting from one GIS format to another.

Say from SHP >> DWG >> SHP

If yes, by what amount?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What results did you get when you tried this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

Some formats will have precision limitations. So a coordinate of:

2.809808098098098089089098

Might be rounded to:

2.8098080981

There may also be issues with how a file format interprets a projection. So a seven parameter defined reprojection projection might not be supported by a file format, so it may revert to the three parameter. Then when converting back it might be reprojected (MapInfo for example, is prone to this), inducing a shift.

But for the most part no.